# How to make Jackson take @JsonView into account when serializing ANY response in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to implement the following functionality: when serializing my dto model in the response from a controller method, it *usually* should be returned without a couple of fields (e.g. `name` field), but for some select endpoints the model should be returned in full (with the `name` field).

To implement it, I've marked the field in my model that I want to usually hide from the response with a `@JsonView` as such:

```
@JsonView(View.Detail.class)
private String name;
```

and I've set the DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION property to `true`, the idea being that if I **don't put a `@JsonView` annotation on a controller method, it will return the model without the `name` field**:
the enabled property would make Jackson serialize every field in the model without a `@JsonView` annotation, and `name` shouldn't be serialized because, well, no view is set, so specifically `View.Detail` is not set, so the field that expects this view should not be serialized.

However it doesn't work this way. When I don't mark a controller method with `@JsonView`, it appears that Jackson is completely disregarding **any** `@JsonView` annotations on the model and serializes **everything** when returning the response from this method.

Only way to make it work, is to annotate every single controller method where I want my default functionality (dto model serialized without the `name` field) with a dummy `@JsonView(View.SomeDummyView.class)`. When I do this, because I enabled DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, it again serializes everything without a `@JsonView` annotation, and doesn't serialize the `name`, because it requires `View.Details.class` view, not the `View.SomeDummyView.class`.

Now my question: how can I force Jackson to validate the `@JsonView` annotations on fields in the model for **every** response it serializes, even if the controller method that generates this response is not annotated with `@JsonView`?